# How to access an iframe within the active page DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have this Google Chrome extension where I want to access the active page, not the Google Chrome extension DOM, however, when I continue to try to access the DOM, I keep getting either NULL or nothing.

For example, when I have an iframe with the ID 'JobOrderWnd', it keeps defaulting it to null, even though on the Google Chrome JavaScript Console, I am able to get the specific iframe required by it.

`document.getElementById('JobOrderWnd').contentWindow.location.href` will return null when it's in the Chrome Extension, but will return with the specific href when typed into the console.

Is there a specific way that I can call this piece of code within the Chrome Extension without it returning null, and instead giving me the href when it's valid?

Comment: Where are you trying to run the code? In the popup? In the background? As an injected script?

Comment: I'm trying to run the code in the background to get the DOM of the active page.

Comment: Does the iframe already have the id **JobOrderWnd** or did you add it using your extension?

Comment: It already has the id of `JobOrderWnd`.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote a chrome extension, but I seem to remember that the only way you can access the document of a page is from within an injected content script. So you will have to inject a content script that talks to the dom, you can then send messages between the background and the content using the Chrome extension api.

Comment: The question needs [MCVE](/help/mcve), otherwise we can only guess. For example, if you already use a content script and that iframe is same-origin, the reason may be that iframe is added slightly after your content script runs so you need to wait for it using setTimeout/setInterval or MutationObserver, and then check if the iframe has been loaded, otherwise add a `load` event listener on it, which will be able to access the contents.